# How to search for file with partial wildcard in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I need to search for filename AM*GQ, where * is sequence eg 344

Can i do this vbs?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `instr()`

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions should work.

```
pattern = "[A][M][0-9]*[G][Q].*"
stringToSearch = "AM432GQ.txt"
MsgBox RegExTest(pattern,stringToSearch)

Function RegExTest(pattern, stringToSearch)
   Dim regEx, Match, Matches   ' Create variable.
   Set regEx = New RegExp   ' Create a regular expression.
   regEx.Pattern = pattern   ' Set pattern.
   regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.
   regEx.Global = True   ' Set global applicability.
   Set Matches = regEx.Execute(stringToSearch)   ' Execute search.
   For Each Match in Matches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
      RetStr = RetStr & "Match found at position "
      RetStr = RetStr & Match.FirstIndex & ". Match Value is '"
      RetStr = RetStr & Match.Value & "'." & vbCRLF
   Next
   RegExTest = RetStr
End Function
```

Comment: Not to condone c&p fixes, but `Set Matches = regEx.Execute(strng)` should be `Set Matches = regEx.Execute(string)`

Comment: @user66001 no.  The parameter that is passed to the function, is `strng`.  If you make the change you suggest, the code will throw an error.